# Is there any way to Power on Android device after switched off, programatically?

Tags: android, service, device, reboot

Actually, i want to include a functionality in my android app that when phone is switched off due to low charging, then when i'll connect Power cable or charger to it, then it will booted up or Power on automatically without pressing Power button physically.

Can we make any service keep alive after device switched off ??

is it possible any how?? plz help by sharing your views & exp.

Comment: try receive broadcast for battery change

Comment: Does broadcast receiver work after device switch off

Comment: with switched off you mean, device goes to sleep mode or is completely turned off?

Comment: when device completely turned off

Comment: @khushhalgoyal when device goes off there is no way to detect anything remotely